# How to use overview map with atlas plugin in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm using atlas plugin to batch generate maps. I insert an overview map but it doesn't get updated over iteration and generation of maps.Is it possible? If it's not, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in 2.0 but in the next version it will be (in the nightly if you want to test).

In 2.2 you can now tell the composer to work on as many map frames as you would like.  Only one coverage layer can be used but this allows you to have the overview map move with the main map frame/s

Comment: Can I get it from here?  git://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git